# Python function for message flow between nodes of a graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

Does anyone know a Python function that can allow me to send information about a node such as the node features to its neighbour? For example: sharing the identity of a node, say node 3 (e.g. address) with its neighbours, say node 2.
[Simple Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAv89.png)

```
nodes = [n for n in table][1:]
node_names = [n[0] for n in nodes]
edgeList = [(1,3), (2,4), (2,3), (3,4)]
G = nx.Graph() #Creates an empty graph with no nodes and no edges
G.add_nodes_from(node_names) #adds nodes to the empty graph G
G.add_edges_from(edgeList)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are few packages that you can try. (1) StellarGraph if you use Tensorflow/Keras, (2) DAG if you use PyTorch and (3) DGL for Tehsorflow & PyTorch. I believe these 3 libraries are able to help.

Comment: Are there libraries that have been used before for such purposes but not in the context of graph learning, GCN, GNN, etc? Something that can allow me to send, for instance, a node ID of one node to another or a requestMessage for the node ID of the other node.

Comment: Short answer: YES. For example, you can find GAT, GraphSAGE, etc..  in these libraries. https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/README.html#example-gcn

Answer (score 0):

Another library with many GNNs implemented is [`pytorch-geometric`](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is based on PyTorch. See the [introduction](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/introduction.html) or the overview of implemented GNNs, [here](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/cheatsheet.html).